# How to use MS SOAP toolkit?

Tags: c++, soap

I know that the Microsoft SOAP toolkit has been deprecated for a while now (.NET has all this stuff built in) but I was wondering in anyone has a quick bit of info on setting up a simple app that uses it. I was referred to 
http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/Building-A-SOAP-Client-With-Visual-C-plus/
but the service in the example is no longer functioning and I can't seem to find any documentation online.

I've looked into gSoap, but it seems overly complicated for what I have to do and despite not being able to get it to work, the SOAP toolkit seems (relatively) elegant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't do it.  It's 5 years deprecated, and it was 2 years out of date when it became deprecated.  Don't.

Assuming you are running on Windows (since you mentioned the MS SOAP Toolkit), use the imminently-arriving [WWSAPI](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wwsapi) instead.

Also see this post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/03/31/interested-in-using-web-services-in-your-native-c-c-code.aspx

**EDIT:** If you want something more basic, you can use MSXML and build your SOAP requests manually.

Comment: I'd go as far as to say you'd be better off using MSXML than the SOAP Toolkit.

Comment: Absolutely.  That's what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Really. "Deprecated" is not the word for it. It's at the top of my list of obsolete web service technologies:

1. SOAP Toolkit
2. WSE 1.0
3. WSE 2.0
4. WSE 3.0
5. ASMX - not quite obsolete. Just "legacy".