# Classic ASP SOAP Server

Tags: soap, asp-classic

I have to create a Classic ASP soap server that will respond to soap requests.
What is the best way to do this?

I read that using the SOAP toolkit is discouraged. Are there other options apart from manually creating the response?

Rgds,

Karel

Comment: Source for the toolkit being discouraged?

Comment: For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196039/does-anyone-know-how-to-use-ms-soap-toolkit

Comment: Could we get a few more details?  When you say "classic asp", do you mean a pre-.Net ASP service application, or a SOAP Web Service using earlier project templates from within ASP.Net?  If you do require old, ASP, why is that the case?  ASP is pretty deprecated.

Comment: Hi RLH,
It's pre-.Net: Active Server Pages.  I know ASP is deprecated, but it is an add-on for an existing ASP application
The application itself cannot be converted for the moment.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/ASP/An-Introduction-To-XML-SOAP-Using-ASP-and-VB6/

Comment: Hi Matt, this will help.
Can you change your comment into an answer so that I can mark it as answer?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use REST services? They are lighter, cleaner and they tend to be more friendly as *[the main difference (between SOAP and REST) is that an RPC (remote procedure call - SOAP) service reinvents bicycle by designing it's own application protocol in the RPC API with the semantics that only it knows. Therefore, all clients have to understand this protocol prior to using the service](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12500861/544283)*. Even you could use them from **any** device as long as it can handle HTTP.

Comment: Esteban, this is a B2B application we have to integrate into our customer's system.
The B2B app uses SOAP and the customer's system's interface is based on ASP